# Bootstrap datepicker: global default date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I'm adding Bootstrap datepicker to my app as follows:

```
<%= f.date_field :date, 'data-provide': 'datepicker' %>
```

I would like a date format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'. I know I could do this using:

```
<%= f.date_field :date, class: 'datefield' %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datefield').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
  });
</script>
```

This would mean though that on every page of my app that uses such date fields, I need to add this code. *Is there a way instead to set the format for datepicker one time **globally**?* So that perhaps I can continue to use the line at the top of my post.

Comment: You can add this script in your application.js file.

Comment: Would you then include `<script ...` all the way up to and including `</script>`? Would you add this at the bottom of application.js file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set a default format

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
```

check full documentation [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/docs/index.rst)

Comment: Thanks, where / in which file would you do this?

Comment: welcome, You can do it in initialization after page load, in $(document).ready

Comment: If you mean which file, then this will depend on how you manage your js code, may be you can add the $(document).ready part in a utilities.js file and require this file in application.js AFTER require bootstarp datepicker

Comment: Thanks I added `$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "dd/mm/yyyy";` to a new file I created in `app/assets/javascripts/filename.js`. At the end of `application.js` (before `.self`) I added `//= require filename`. It seems to work. Please let me know, if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default date format.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
})
```

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html?highlight=format